# Created app with rails composer but cannot launch rails in the app directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

Using Rails Composer (http://railsapps.github.com/rails-composer/) I created a new app, but I'm unable to run rails in the app newly created app directory, even though rails can be run everywhere else.

```
user@UBUNTU:~$ rails
Usage:
rails new APP_PATH [options] ...

user@UBUNTU:~$ cd myapp/
user@UBUNTU:~/myapp$ rails
The program 'rails' can be found in the following packages: ...
```

Using Ubuntu 12.10 and rvm

Comment: what do you get after entering `ruby -v`

Comment: I have ruby 2.0.0 installed and just installed ruby 1.9.3 for this one. ruby -v gives "1.9.3" when launched in myapp/ directory and otherwise "2.0.0". The app has its own .rvmrc with a specific gemset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running RVM? If so is there an .rvmrc file that is tied to a gemset?  If that's the case there may not be a rails gem in that gemset.

Type `rvm gemset list` to see what gemsets have been created.

Comment: gemsets for ruby-1.9.3-p392 (found in /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392)
   (default)
   global
=> myapp

Comment: Then do a `gem list`.  If you don't see rails you'll need to run `gem install rails` to install it or just `bundle install` to install all the gems you have in my Gemfile.  They'll be added to the global gemset.